# AWS S3 lifecycle rule for folder with no contents, does the folder get deleted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

lets say I put a rule to prefix "logs/" and dont have any contents inside, and my day of expiration is set to 1 day.

After 1 day, does logs folder get deleted? or it only applies to objects created inside that prefix, and they get deleted after 1 day of each respective object file creation?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in S3 there are no folders. S3 is essentially a key-value storage, where the keys are strings, identifiers for the objects and the values are the objects stored.

Your keys can mimic a folder structure, the AWS console will show as if you would have folders for organizational purposes, but under the hood there are no folders. Since there are no folders, when you delete the last object with a folder like suffix, the "folder" will also disappear. So, if everything from `logs/` is deleted, the `log` "folder" will also be deleted.

You may be able to have "empty folders". From the AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html):

> When you use the Amazon S3 console to create a folder, Amazon S3 creates a 0-byte object with a key that's set to the folder name that you provided. For example, if you create a folder named photos in your bucket, the Amazon S3 console creates a 0-byte object with the key photos/. The console creates this object to support the idea of folders.

If you would want to keep your `logs\` prefix, you may want to create the policy in a way to exclude this `0-byte` file.